# How to calculate weighted mean when your sample is unweighted, but you know your population

Tags: descriptive-statistics, survey, weights, weighted-mean, poststratification

Lets say I have the following **sample** data.

```
person_id   gender  age_group   cluster buys    sells   gender_age
0   1   F   Y   1   8   4.5 F_Y
1   2   F   O   2   12  4.8 F_O
2   3   F   O   3   10  5.1 F_O
3   4   F   O   1   13  5.5 F_O
4   5   M   Y   2   14  3.8 M_Y
5   6   M   Y   3   7   5.2 M_Y
6   7   M   Y   2   5   5.8 M_Y
7   8   M   O   1   16  4.7 M_O
8   9   M   Y   2   12  4.5 M_Y
```

where `M` denotes `Male`, `F` denotes `Female`, `Y` denotes `Young` and `O` denotes `Old`.

I also have the **population** `gender-age_group` distribution which is the following

```
  gender age_group  percentage
0      F         O        0.16
1      F         Y        0.18
2      M         O        0.16
3      M         Y        0.50
```

which means that in my population I have `0.16 + 0.18 = 34% Females`, `18%` `Young Females`, `50% Old Males` etc.

I would like to calculate the `weighted` `buys` and `sells`, for each of the `gender-age_group` splits.

I have thought of 2 ways:

1. Calculate the average e.g. `buys` for each  `gender-age_group` split, for the `Old Females` that would be `(12+10+13) / 3 = 11.6667`
   and then multiply this with the respective factor (`percentage`) from my population table, which for the `Old Females` would be `0.16`. So the end `weighted_buys` for the `Old Females` would be `11.6667 * 0.16`
2. For each person_id in my **sample** data, obtain a post-stratification weight using iterative raking by using e.g. [weightipy](https://pypi.org/project/weightipy/) or [quantipy](https://github.com/Quantipy/quantipy), I would end up with something like this

> ```
> person_id gender  age_group   cluster buys    sells   gender_age  weights
> 0 1   F   Y   1   8   4.5 F_Y 1.620
> 1 2   F   O   2   12  4.8 F_O 0.480
> 2 3   F   O   3   10  5.1 F_O 0.480
> 3 4   F   O   1   13  5.5 F_O 0.480
> 4 5   M   Y   2   14  3.8 M_Y 1.125
> 5 6   M   Y   3   7   5.2 M_Y 1.125
> 6 7   M   Y   2   5   5.8 M_Y 1.125
> 7 8   M   O   1   16  4.7 M_O 1.440
> 8 9   M   Y   2   12  4.5 M_Y 1.125
> ```

and then for the `Old Females` the `weighted_buys` would be `(12*0.480+10*0.480+13*0.480) / (0.480+0.480+0.480)`

Which way is the correct one ?